# Are there benchmarks for assessing the speed of the forward-pass of neural networks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, feedforward-neural-networks, benchmarks

I have a task where I would like to use a convolutional neural network (CNN). I would like to incrementally start from the fastest models, fine-tune and see whether they fit my "budget". At the moment, I'm just looking at object detection CNN-based feedforward models.

I'm curious to know if there is any article, blog, web page or gist that benchmarks the popular CNN models based on the forward-pass speed. If there is back-propagation time and dataset-wise performance, even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks might be a good start. It mostly focuses on GPUs, but there is also one CPU (Dual Xeon E5-2630 v3).